# Java bindiings for XLib

Tags: java, xlib

I'm looking for Java bindings for XLib.

Specially, I need to be able to reparent an X windows application from within Java.

Ideally I would like to do this by making the X windows calls directly from java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about XLib... but recently I ran across [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) and it seems that it can talk with system APIs so give it a look if you wish:

http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.4.0/javadoc/

Good Luck!

Comment: Github link is out of date.

Comment: @wscourge, wow, 7 and a half years ago, I never would have remembered this answer... Anyway, I tried to backtrack on the original link and came up with an alternative that I think captures what I had in mind. So... here is the original one in case anyone wants to give a better alternative: https://github.com/twall/jna/nonav/javadoc/index.html?com/sun/jna/examples/unix/package-summary.html

Comment: 7.5 years ago, still useful. Wonderful website, thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 0):

I've created xcb (successor of xlib) bindings for Java through SWiG. You can find the code here:

https://github.com/Zubnix/xcb4j

It's a rather large but straightforward implementation and should work once you have all the required xcb module headers installed.

Comment: @Zubzub would you mind being more specific on how I can run the code generation? I'd love to have XCB bindings in Java.

Comment: @IngoBürk Please put your question on github. That way xcb4j related issues remain centralised. :)